# cauchy mean value theorem on open interval

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

How can I prove that forall $0 < x < 1 $ :
$$ \frac{2\ln x}{2\arcsin x-\pi} < \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} $$
 with the **Cauchy's mean value theorem** that requires continuous in a closed interval and differentiable in a open interval, which I don't have since $\ln 0$ is not defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(u) =\ln u , h(u) =\arcsin u $ then you have $$\frac{2 \ln u }{2\arcsin u -\pi} =\frac{f(1) -f(x)}{g(1) - g(x) }=\frac{f '(s)}{g ' (s)} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{s^2 } -1 } <\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 } -1} $$

since $1>s>x .$